# SSRS , show negative results as zeros in the textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Currently I am using this as custom Format of the text box in SSRS to show negative numbers as zeros 
Is this correct format

'$'#,0.00;-'$',0.00
[image]

Comment: Can you use an IIF expression that compares the value to 0, if it's less than 0 then display 0?

Comment: Yes , that's what I did , but my IIF has 60 different conditions , so thinking of an alternate solution, which might  improve the performance